# Access user home directory

Tags: plugins, adobe-brackets

Currently I am writing a plugin for Brackets where I want to access the user home directory. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to to this and for me it is looking like Brackets isn't supporting this.
In NodeJS I simply would use `var homedir  = require('os').homedir()`.

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Brackets API and not node-modules to do this.

For example this is their  'class' for getting contents from a directory.

http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/filesystem/Directory.html

Comment: The Problem is not the  access to the file system. The problem is to get the path to the user home directory. The NodeJS code snippet is just how I would do it in NodeJS. and I am looking to an equivalent in Brackets.

Comment: Ah I see, I apologize!  I wish I had a better answer for you.